# Fully customizable layout?

Tags: javascript, css, customization, dhtml

Is it possible to make a fully customizable website layout? Preferably in javascript/dhtml, if possible. I'm making a whack a mole game and I would like users to be able to position the holes in which the moles come out of anywhere on the webpage. My current code is sloppy, as I'm just experimenting on ways to do it, but my current code is

```
<html>

<body>

<!--CURSOR-->
<style type="text/css">
body, a, a:hover {cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/others/oth-5/oth438.cur),
progress;}
</style>

<!--BACKGROUND-->
<body background = "http://i52.tinypic.com/34e9ekj.jpg">

<!--COUNTER(needs to be implemnted)-->
<b><center><font size="5"><div id='counter'>0</div></font></center><b>

<!--TITLE-->
<b><center><i>Whack-A-Mole</i> - by Steven</center></b>

<!--HOLE IMAGES START HERE-->

<!--Hole 1 Row 1-->
<img src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif' style="margin-left:33px;margin-top:3px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 2 Row 1-->
<img src="http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif" style="margin-left:350px;margin-top:3px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 3 Row 1-->
<img src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif' style="margin-left:700px;margin-top:3px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 4 Row 2-->
<img src="http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif" style="margin-left:33px;margin-top:160px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 5 Row 2-->
<img src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif' style="margin-left:350px;margin-top:160px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 6 Row 2-->
<img src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif' style="margin-left:700px;margin-top:160px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 7 Row 3-->
<img src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif' style="margin-left:33px;margin-top:310px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 8 Row 3-->
<img src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif' style="margin-left:350px;margin-top:310px;position:absolute"/>

<!--Hole 9 Row 3-->
<img src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif' style="margin-left:700px;margin-top:310px;position:absolute"/>
<!--HOLE IMAGES END HERE-->

<!--MOLE DIVS START HERE-->

<!--Mole 1 Row 1-->
<div id="randomdiv1" 
class="mole">
<img src="http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif" style="margin-left:33px;margin-top:3px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 2 Row 1-->
<div id="randomdiv2" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole1" src ='http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif' style="margin-left:350px;margin-top:3px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 3 Row 1-->
<div id="randomdiv3" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole2" src ='http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif' style="margin-left:700px;margin-top:3px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 4 Row 2-->
<div id="randomdiv4" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole3" src ='http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif' style="margin-left:33px;margin-top:160px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 5 Row 2-->
<div id="randomdiv5" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole4" src ='http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif' style="margin-left:350px;margin-top:160px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 6 Row 2-->
<div id="randomdiv6" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole5" src ='http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif' style="margin-left:700px;margin-top:160px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 7 Row 3-->
<div id="randomdiv7" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole6" src="http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif" style="margin-left:33px;margin-top:310px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 8 Row 3-->
<div id="randomdiv8" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole8" src ='http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif' style="margin-left:350px;margin-top:310px;position:absolute"/>
</div>

<!--Mole 9 Row 3-->
<div id="randomdiv9" 
class="mole">
<img id="Mole9" src ='http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif' style="margin-left:700px;margin-top:310px;position:absolute"/>
</div>
</body>

<!--MOLE DIVS END HERE-->

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

<!--
// Type the number of div containers to randomly display below.

NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay = 9;

var CookieName = 'DivRamdomValueCookie';
function DisplayRandomDiv() {
var r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay);
if(NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay > 1) {
   var ck = 0;
   var cookiebegin = document.cookie.indexOf(CookieName + "=");
   if(cookiebegin > -1) {
      cookiebegin += 1 + CookieName.length;
      cookieend = document.cookie.indexOf(";",cookiebegin);
      if(cookieend < cookiebegin) { cookieend = document.cookie.length; }
      ck = parseInt(document.cookie.substring(cookiebegin,cookieend));
      }
   while(r == ck) { r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay); }
   document.cookie = CookieName + "=" + r;
   }
for( var i=1; i<=NumberOfDivsToRandomDisplay; i++) {
   document.getElementById("randomdiv"+i).style.display="none";
   }

<!--Make counter +1 on mole click-->

document.getElementById("randomdiv"+r).onclick = function() {
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
document.getElementById("randomdiv"+r).style.display="block";
}

<!--Make moles pop up randomly on a timer-->
DisplayRandomDiv()
setInterval("DisplayRandomDiv()",(Math.random()*500) + 1000);
//-->
</script>

</head>

</html>
```

I'm not sure if it's even possible or not, but meh, might as well ask. :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You could throw a bunch of elements on the page and then absolutely position them anywhere you wanted. You'd have to pay attention to z-index issues to make sure your moles are on top and whackable.

You'd want to give each mole hole a (unique) `id` attribute to make them easy to reference. Then, you'd just need to set them to `position:absolute` and add `top` and `left` CSS properties to put them where you want them. BTW, margins on absolutely positioned elements [don't do anything useful because](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning):

> It is removed from the normal flow entirely (it has no impact on later siblings). An absolutely positioned box establishes a new containing block for normal flow children and absolutely (but not fixed) positioned descendants. However, the contents of an absolutely positioned element do not flow around any other boxes.

So get rid of the margins and use `top` and `left` to put your `<img>` elements where you want them.

You'd probably want to use JavaScript to position your holes, that would make it easier to account for varying page sizes.

Comment: I kinda get what your saying but would that actually allow the end user to drag the holes where they wanted?

Comment: @Steven: How do you feel about using jQuery-UI or a similar library? I wouldn't recommend doing drag'n'drop by hand. jQuery-UI for the drag'n'drop, cookies for keeping track of things, and proper CSS positioning should get the job done.